# Magento 2 get keys values in rest api response

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, php, php-7.2

```
    {
        "item_id": 191111111,
        "sku": "qqqqqqq",
        "qty": 1,
        "name":"asdasd",
        "price": 736.52,
        "product_type": "simple",
        "quote_id": "1111",
        "product_option": {
            "extension_attributes": {
                "custom_options": [
                    {
                        "option_id": "1111",
                        "option_value": "12131111111089"
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    }
```

i want to get the option_id and vales from it Anyone can help?

Answer (score 0):

Use this below code for get option id and option value :

```
public function __construct(\Magento\Checkout\Model\Cart $cart)
{
    $this->cart = $cart;
}
```

---

```
$cartItem =  $this->cart->getItems();
$customOptions = $cartItem->getProductOption()->getExtensionAttributes()->getCustomOptions();
if (!empty($customOptions) && is_array($customOptions)) {
    $requestData = [];
    foreach ($customOptions as $option) {
        $requestData['options'][$option->getOptionId()] = $option->getOptionValue();
    }
}
```

- **$option->getOptionId()** => You will get option_id
- **$option->getOptionValue()** => You will get option_value

Comment: How can i add the cartitem into dependency?

Comment: Do you have quote item variable/ object?

Comment: I am getting response in using Rest api
http://localhost/Project/rest/ar/V1/carts/mine/items

Comment: Check my updated answer.